# Prove that $X´$ is a closed set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X\subset \mathbb{R}$.I have to prove,for all $X$ that $X´$,i.e, the set of accumulation points, is a closed set.

Well,I know , by definition, that every accumulation point is a point of closure.

How a set is said to be closed if $X = \overline X$ ,and how the accumulations points are

points of closure,then:

$X´=\overline X$.

So $X´ $ is closed.

Is that right?

Comment: Let $X=\{0\}$. Then $X'=\varnothing$, and $\overline X=X$, so in this case $X'\ne\overline X$.

Comment: Oh!My bad!Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $x\notin X'$. Then $x$ has an open nbhd $N$ such that $N\cap X\subseteq\{x\}$. (Why?) What can you say about $N\cap X'$?

Comment: You mean $N\cap X\subseteq\{x\}$.

Comment: @Asaf: Yep; thanks.

Comment: Is $N\cap X´ = \emptyset$?

Comment: @MeAndMath What you want to prove is that **no** $x$ outside of $X'$ can be a limit point of $X'$, which will let you conclude that any limit point must be contained in $X'$, from where it follows $X'$ must be closed.

Comment: @PeterTamaroff THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!

Comment: @MeAndMath Could you prove it?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff Think I can...